# Finding multiple column duplicates in a string array and consolidating them in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, loops

I've got a 2 column cell of character arrays, and a numerical array of the same length. If both columns match then I want to consolidate those rows by deleting them and summing the numerical array rows.

For example, if one row of string is `{'abd','123'}` and there is another `{'abd','123'}` then I want all those indices so that I can print out a CSV file with 3 columns where the first 2 rows are unique and the 3rd is summation of the duplicates.

I am using MATLAB 2012.

```
textdata = {'1','3','6','6','12','12','12','4','1'}';
textdata(:,2) = {'c','q','r','r','s','b','s','q','d'}';
nums = [1,4,5,6,7,3,2,23,34]';
```

so this is similar to what I have I just read in a csv file and 2 of the columns were char strings like '223455'and '23455x' so im just trying to duplicate with smaller data set. And Im using ur way of solving but doesnt work on rows as u said.

```
% At = table(A(:,1), A(:,2));
[At2,~,ID] = unique(textdata,'rows');
At2.Var3 = accumarray(ID, nums(:));
% writetable(At2, 'output.csv', 'WriteVariableNames', false);
```

Comment: @rayryeng the data is a cell array of characters I think

Comment: @AlexByasse OK, well that changes things.  I'll have to edit my answer because it's not valid anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the data from your example, let's set it up like so...

```
myCell = {'1', '3', '6', '6', '12', '12', '12', '4', '1';
          'c', 'q', 'r', 'r', 's',  'b',  's',  'q', 'd'}.';
nums = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 2, 23, 34].';
```

So we want to consolidate the `'6', 'r'` rows and the `'12', 's'` rows.

Now if your data was all numerical, we could use `unique(myData, 'rows')`, but `'rows'` isn't supported for cell arrays. We can call `unique` once, `reshape` the result, then call `unique` again on the *indices*. Because the indices are numerical, we can now use `'rows'`!

```
% Get unique strings, use stable so result isn't sorted
% To start with, we are only interested in the indices of duplicate items, didx
[~, ~, didx] = unique(myCell, 'stable'); 
% Reshape back to 2 columns and run unique on the rows
% This time we also save the indices of the unique rows, uidx
[~, uidx, didx] = unique(reshape(didx, [], 2), 'rows', 'stable');
```

Now you can now use `accumarray` and some concatenation to get the result

```
result = [myCell(uidx, :), num2cell(accumarray(didx, nums))];

>> result =
      { '1'  'c'  1
        '3'  'q'  4
        '6'  'r'  11
        '12' 's'  9
        '12' 'b'  3
        '4'  'q'  23
        '1'  'd'  34 }
% Note how the '6','r' and '12','s' rows have values of 11=6+5 and 9=7+2 respectively
```

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to convert your string array into a table, use [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) on this table so that we can establish an ID that maps to each row, then finally use [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to perform the desired summation.  Given your rather limited example, let's say that `A` contained your string array and `B` contained your numerical array of the same size.

Therefore:

```
At = table(A(:,1), A(:,2));
[At2,~,ID] = unique(At);
At2.Var3 = accumarray(ID, B(:));
writetable(At2, 'output.csv', 'WriteVariableNames', false);
```

The first line of code converts your string array into an actual table where each column is a column from your string array.  We then use the third output of `unique` to convert each row of your table to a unique integer ID so that rows with the same ID mean that their row contents are equal.  The first output of `unique` provides us with a new table that only contains the unique rows of your table.  We then use `accumarray` so that we group all of the rows with the same IDs together and we use `B` to access these corresponding locations provided by the IDs and we sum the values together.  This is the default behaviour of `accumarray`.  The output of `accumarray` will have the same number of rows as the unique table and the order is such that each element gives us the sum of those rows that share the same pair of strings in a row.  We then add a new column to this table and write this to a CSV file called `output.csv`.  I've ignored the column headings creating a `table` in the above code provides filler column headings and that's probably not what you want.

As a quick example, supposing that `A` and `B` are:

```
>> A = string({'abd', '123'; 'abd', '123'; 'abcc', '1234'; 'abdef', '34567'})

A = 

  4×2 string array

    "abd"      "123"  
    "abd"      "123"  
    "abcc"     "1234" 
    "abdef"    "34567"

>> B = [3; 4; 6; -1]

B =

     3
     4
     6
    -1
```

Running the above code gives us the following table:

```
>> At2

At2 = 

     Var1       Var2      Var3
    _______    _______    ____

    "abcc"     "1234"      6  
    "abd"      "123"       7  
    "abdef"    "34567"    -1
```

We can see that each row gives us the sum of all numerical values that share the same locations from the string array.  The first two rows of this matrix have the same pair of strings, so their corresponding values of 3 and 4 get added to 7.  You can verify the rest of the table yourself.

Comment: I have matlab 2012 so no table()! Any other way of doing it??

Comment: If you have Matlab 2012 **(a or b?)** then you also don't have strings, which solves what was discussed in the question's comments. You can do the exact same without first converting to a table.

Comment: I used `table` because you alluded to a `string` array.  `table`s were introduced before strings so I naturally assumed you could use a string array.  This brings us to what we talked about by providing a **small example** so we don't get confused.  Please update your question.

Comment: Error using accumarray
Second input VAL must be a vector with one element for each row in SUBS, or a scalar. So unique gives me an 11 row vector when my matrix is 9x2? and my num vector only has 9 rows

Comment: You'd have to modify `unique` to operate on a rows basis, but that doesn't work with a cell array which is why you're getting those errors.  I'll have to change my answer as you don't have a MATLAB version that supports what I wrote above. As a minor sidenote, I have no idea why you're using a MATLAB version that's 5 years old.  You should upgrade.

Comment: @rayryeng I've written an answer which works with older versions. You can certainly do it more elegantly in newer versions, but "your software is too old" probably isn't a helpful tip most the time heh!

Comment: @Wolfie heh yes I suppose. Btw very clever converting to indices first then using unique on the result. I'll leave my answer here for those who have newer versions.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks, in fact I realise you can just use 2 `unique` calls, not 3 like I put originally... makes it slightly less clunky.